# How do I retrieve the ModelView matrix in GLSL 1.5?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have been reading through the specification of openGL 1.5, and saw that any reference to what used to be a variable holding the reference to the ModelView matrix (like gl_ModelViewMatrix) has been deprecated, and is only availble in some kind of compatability mode (which happens not to be supported on my GPU).

I have seen a few examples first retrieving the ModelView matrix or creating one, then sending it back to the GPU as a uniform variable.

Now this all seems just backward to me; even for a simple Vertex Shader you will in many cases want to use some kind of transformation on the geometry.

So I am really wondering now; is there *any* way to get the current ModelView matrix from within a vertex shader, using GLSL 1.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenGL-3 core completely dropped the matrix stack, i.e. the built-in modelview, projection, texture and color matrices. It's now expected from you to implement the matrix math and supply the matrices through self chosen uniforms.

Comment: well, that explains it. Not sure if I like it, though.

Comment: @Bartvbl: Well, no practical application actually used the matrix stack other than loading the matrix produced somewhere else with glLoadMatrix. Every animation system will emit the animation data as ready to use matrix. For view calculations you already have the projection and view matrices around for uses in other code than OpenGL. So the whole matrix stack actually was kind of redundant and became cumbersome to use. Doing it through free definable uniforms is much more convenient once a program reaches a certain complexity.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in matrix system/lib in core openGL - since 3.+ version.
A lot of people had similar (bad) opinions about that "huge change" in openGL.

You have to use your own set of functions to perform matrix calculation. See libraries like: [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/) or in [lighthouse3D](http://www.lighthouse3d.com).

All in all it was very useful to have matrix functions in OpenGL when learning. Now you have to look for other solutions...
On the other side it is not a problem for game engines or game frameworks that usually have their own math libraries. So for them "new" OpenGL is even easier to use.